# NSUserDefaults + Local Notifications

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I use in my app the local notifications for reminders. I need to set any alarm with a name so you have an alarm only for each activity. I would use NSUserDefaults to have key-value. Now I use this system that does not allow me to do this.

```
-(void)scheduleAlarm:(id)sender {

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

// Get the current date
NSDate *pickerDate = [datePicker date];

// Break the date up into components
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit ) 
                                               fromDate:pickerDate];
NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit ) 
                                               fromDate:pickerDate];

// Set up the fire time
NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComps setDay:[dateComponents day]];
[dateComps setMonth:[dateComponents month]];
[dateComps setYear:[dateComponents year]];
[dateComps setHour:[timeComponents hour]];
// Notification will fire in one minute
[dateComps setMinute:[timeComponents minute]];
[dateComps setSecond:[timeComponents second]];
NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];
[dateComps release];

UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (localNotif == nil)
    return;
localNotif.fireDate = itemDate;
localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

// Notification details
localNotif.alertBody = [mainTitle text];
// Set the action button
localNotif.alertAction = @"View";

localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

// Specify custom data for the notification
NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"someValue" forKey:@"someKey"];
localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;

// Schedule the notification
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
[localNotif release];





}
```

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSUserDefaults has this instance method:

```
- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryForKey:(NSString *)defaultName
```

Why not use it to return the dictionary that you need for the `userInfo` property of your Local Notification?